# Python multithreading accessing redis-server?

Tags: python, multithreading, redis

I've read that using multi-threading on CPU-bound task is useless, but if the app is IO-bound then you can expect reasonable speed up.

My question is if the app uses redis-server can I expect a speed up, it is IO-bound or memory-bound task, right !?

Comment: The question is a bit confused. The issue is about *communication* with the Redis server; communication is obviously IO. But I'm not sure where multithreading comes in here. Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: i dont have the code ... i'm trying to decide whether to go with normal dict or redis. If I could get speedup with multithreading i will do redis, because my algorithm will benefit if I can access and update simultaneously i.e. if I can treat the dict more like DB.

Comment: This is completely bass-ackwards. Communicating with Redis is a competely different proposition from keeping a dict. Apart from the complexity of running a separate service, you have the extra overhead of serializing the data, sending the external request to the Redis server, and so on. This is not at all the way to think about "speeding up" your code.

Comment: that is OK .. i can split my code to logically separate modules that I want to work simultaneously. with dict i have to make them serial.